# Deployment to Azure for a Service Bus

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azureservicebus, azure-resource-manager, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm using an ARM template to deploy to Azure. However the Azure Service Bus deployment section is proving difficult.

Can Anyone tell me how to configure the same settings as in the classic Portal, e.g.:
duplicate Detection History Time 
Lock Duration
Maximum Queue Size
Maximum delivery count
Default Message Time to Live

Alternatively is there a way to do it in Powershell and call that from the ARM script instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you can. 
Problem is ServiceBus ARM Template is not well documented (for the moment).

Full template available [here](https://github.com/CrazyTuna/ARM-ServiceBusQueue-Template).

Interesting part:

```
"properties": {
    "path": "[parameters('serviceBusQueueName')]",
    "maxSizeInMegabytes": "2048", 
    "defaultMessageTimeToLive": "7.00:00:00",
    "lockDuration": "00:01:00",
    "enableDuplicateDetection": "true",
    "duplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow": "00:15:00",
    "enablePartitioning": "true",
    "maxDeliveryCount": "5"        
}
```

Here `defaultMessageTimeToLive`, `lockDuration` and `duplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow` are `Timespan`.

My tip when you don't know the name of the property:

- Find the MDSN documentation (C#) to create a queue or topic or subscription (ie: [QueueDescription](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.aspx))
- Look at the properties of the class and just put in the template the same property with camelCase.

Most of the time, it does the trick !

Comment: "enableDuplicateDetection": "true" did not work for me. I had to change to "requiresDuplicateDetection": "true".

Answer (score 0):

Currently these properties cannot be set using the ARM templates directly. You need to configure these using ServiceBus Powershell scripts. 
**Here is the link to sample PS scripts** 
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Service-Bus-PowerShell-a46b7059/sourcecode?fileId=134510&pathId=2004509049

Comment: Hey Tushar, see my answer, it is already possible but not documented :-).

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the info. and sharing the answer. Yes I also did not found any documentation anywhere.

Comment: @Thomas I would suggest you should send a pull request on the Azure quick start templates https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates

Comment: Sure, Could be helpfull for someone else ^^